# Manipulate Blast Result File Python

Tags: python, file, parsing, biopython, blast

I wrote a Biopython scrip which give me result and i have a file like that :

```
>NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE647364.1_346 [38084-37959]
MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET

>NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE646921.1_20 [383-240]
MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET

>NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE647277.1_227 [70875-70720]
MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET
```

How can I get a result on a single comment line like that :

```
>NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE647364.1_346 [38084-37959] | KE646921.1_20 [383-240] | KE647277.1_227 [70875-70720] 
MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET
```

I tried with regex but it doesn't work . Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a FASTA label, everything until the first space is the ID and is supposed to be unique. That's not the case in your example so `SeqIO.to_dict()` won't work. Instead, map the sequences back to their labels and then combine them:

```py
from Bio import SeqIO
from collections import defaultdict

seq2label = defaultdict(list)
for record in SeqIO.parse('result.fa', 'fasta'):
    seq2label[str(record.seq)].append(record.description)

for sequence, labels in seq2label.items():
    combined_label = ' | '.join(labels[:1] + [label.split('|')[1] for label in labels[1:]])
    print(f'>{combined_label}\n{sequence}\n')
```

output:

```
>NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE647364.1_346 [38084-37959] | KE646921.1_20 [383-240] | KE647277.1_227 [70875-70720]
MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET
```

Comment: Any chance You can keep the <class 'Bio.SeqRecord.SeqRecord'> type for the >NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE647364.1_346 [38084-37959] | KE646921.1_20 [383-240] | KE647277.1_227 [70875-70720]
MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET object ??

Comment: @pippo1980 you mean create a SeqRecord instead of a string? I just print the string for convenience but you could do `record = Bio.SeqRecord(sequence, description=combined_label)` and then write them to fasta format in batch.

Comment: Auch it doesn't work: got ID: ID: <unknown id>
Name: <unknown name>
Description: NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE647364.1_346 [38084-37959] | KE646921.1_20 [383-240] | KE647277.1_227 [70875-70720]
Number of features: 0
'MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET' and SeqIO.write(recordz, handle, 'fasta') gives --> TypeError: SeqRecord (id=<unknown id>) has an invalid sequence. Sequence should be something like this: Seq('MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET') –

Comment: from Bio.Seq import Seq recordz = SeqRecord(Seq(sequence), description=combined_label) works but gives seqrecord obj like: ID: ID: <unknown id>
Name: <unknown name>
Description: NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE647364.1_346 [38084-37959] | KE646921.1_20 [383-240] | KE647277.1_227 [70875-70720]
Number of features: 0
Seq('MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET') and saves it like: ><unknown id> NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE647364.1_346 [38084-37959] | KE646921.1_20 [383-240] | KE647277.1_227 [70875-70720]
MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET

Comment: @pippo1980 seems like you have to assign the ID explicitly

Comment: Is there a way to not assign it giving out blank instead of unknown ?

Comment: @pippo1980 you can try to assign a blank but as I said in my answer, the ID is supposed to be unique among the records

Comment: both recordz = SeqRecord(Seq(sequence), description=combined_label, id=combined_label.split()[0]) and recordz = SeqRecord(Seq(sequence), description=combined_label, id='') work but in different ways 1st assign value to id 2nd remove id from SeqRecord object, both are saved as fastas the way original OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

okkey didnt use 'SeqIO.to_dict()' don't know about it maybe someone else will post an answer using that [EDITED

`record_dict = SeqIO.to_dict(SeqIO.parse(fasta_file , "fasta"))`

will raise a

```
raise ValueError("Duplicate key '%s'" % key)
ValueError: Duplicate key 'NW_020169394.1_41'
```

My input 'res.txt' file is:

```
>NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE647364.1_346 [38084-37959]
MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET

>NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE646921.1_20 [383-240]
MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET

>NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE647277.1_227 [70875-70720]
MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET
```

My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Jun 28 15:57:59 2021

@author: Pietro

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68160254/manipulate-blast-result-file-python


"""
from Bio import SeqIO

fasta_file = 'res.txt'


sequences = {}
sequences2 = {}

sequa = SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta")


count = 0
for seq_record in sequa   :
            sequences[count] = seq_record
            count +=1


for key,seq_record in sequences.items():
    countz = 0
    if seq_record.seq not in [valuez.seq for keiz,valuez in sequences2.items()]:
        sequences2[countz] = seq_record
        countz += 1
        
    else:
        for keiz,valuez in sequences2.items():
            if seq_record.seq == valuez.seq:
                new = valuez.description.replace('valuez.id', '')
                newnew = new.replace(valuez.name , '')
                sequences2[keiz].description = seq_record.description + (newnew)
            
            
        
print('########################')
print(sequences2)

with open('modified_res.text', 'w') as handle:
    
    
    for key,value in sequences2.items():
            
           print(value)
           SeqIO.write(value, handle, 'fasta')
```

My output 'modified_res.text' file is:

```
>NW_020169394.1_41 [10497-10619]|KE647277.1_227 [70875-70720] [10497-10619]|KE646921.1_20 [383-240] [10497-10619]|KE647364.1_346 [38084-37959]
MDQLSRKLNLTYLKVGILTSQNEFVTKHLLIIKGLKIFTET
```

cant get rid of duplicated `[10497-10619]` and order is different from yours

sorry, was my best effort

Moreover if your sequences are parsable by a specifit seqrecord format (i.e. genbank and so on , not an expert here , could be possible to play with their description in different way, please let me know).